# Editing a specific cell on a TableView

Tags: java, javafx

I want to edit a specific cell in a TableView using JavaFX (for example, row `3`, column `5`).

I tried this code but it doesn't work.

```
//Define the string
String s = "myString";
//Define the number
int value = 5;
//Synthesize the item = row
Item item = new Item(s, value);
//Set the i-th item
table.getItems().set(i, item);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need? In your example you do not mention any position but the question title does.

```
table.getTableView().getItems().get(
                        t.getTablePosition().getRow())
                        ).setLastName(t.getNewValue()
```

You can find [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/TableViewSample.java.html) a complete example.

Answer (score 0):

Just edit the list you are providing to the table to what you want and just call

```
yourtable.refresh();
```